# Python: How to parallel scrape urls which are yet to be discovered?

Tags: python, concurrency, web-scraping

This is what I have:

**Starting URL:** `http://domain.tld/articles`

**End URL:** `http://domain.tld/articles/?page=500`
Am just giving example for end URL. In normal conditions end URL is unknown and can vary.

From starting URL there is link to next URL with class `search-more`, for example URL pointing to `?page=2`, then from second page there is a link to third page like `?page=3` and so on. In this example page number 499 will not have next link.

If I try to hit non existing URL, for example page 501, I will know two things:

1. There is class `.not-found`
2. Class `.not-found` contains text `Page doesnt exist`

I need to create parallel fetching of all this pages.

I found that this is easy to do that if I have all necessary URLs already defined in a list, for example:

```
urls = [
'http://domain.tld/articles/'
'http://domain.tld/articles/?page=2'
'http://domain.tld/articles/?page=3'
'http://domain.tld/articles/?page=4'
 ...
'http://domain.tld/articles/?page=500'
]
```

But I have no idea how I can do this with all URLs with threading.

This is my code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import sys
import lxml.html
import time
ts = time.time()

i = 1
co = len(urls)

def parse(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page.content)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:

    future_to_url = {executor.submit(parse, url): url for url in urls}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        t = i/(time.time() - ts)
        print('Iterations per second: %.2f (%d/%d)' % (t, i, co), end='\r')
        i += 1

total_time = time.time() - ts
print('')
print('Running time: %s' % total_time)
```

So the code above work only when I define `urls` (which is expected).

As I stated before I will not have all URLs, just the starting one.

What and how should I create `urls list`?

Comment: I use `multiprocessing.dummy` for threading. You could use a `queue` for urls list. I don't think that you can dynamically alter it if you are used pool execution. You might have to manually create a pool of threads, but there are examples at the bottom of the help. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: The code that i provided is working when i have urls, and it works great. The problem is that i dont know how can i utilize it in order to discover more paginated urls from starting url.

Comment: Yes. That is why I mentioned a queue. Spawn a bunch of processes, add some items to the queue. The processes read an url from the queue. While processing a url, they add new urls to the queue. When done, they try to read a new url from the queue. If the queue is empty, they can sleep and try again later. You could also have a shared array where Processes can indicate whether they are done. Once all of the processes indicate they are done and the queue is empty, close it all down. Use threadsafe variables.

Comment: Im not sure what im doing, but this is not any faster than now. More specifically, here is the problem that i dont know what would be the best and fastest way to fetch paginated links. Using queue  is not speeding things for me, because when i fetch paginated page i already have result. Maybe im mistaken somewhere...